# Open Source XMPP server for IM

Tags: xmpp, instant-messaging

I would like to build Instant Messaging service for my company. I have got familiar with XMPP from this book. Now I would like to play with some open source existing XMPP servers and build Instant Messaging service. Can you recommend any open source XMPP web servers.

P.S: I am new to XMPP and Instant Messaging, so any recommendation regarding XMPP and IM will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

A good list of XMPP servers can be found from this link: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

But few of the main players are jabberd, ejabberd, openfire, Tigase etc.

Answer (score 5):

Recommend [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) as XMPP server and install [candy-chat](http://candy-chat.github.io/candy/) as web interface.

it give freedom to the end-user to choose any [xmpp client](https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) like pidgin or just directly using web interface.

Candy also provides lots of plugins to extend.

Answer (score 2):

If you familiar with java I suggest you this two.

1. openfire - Written in java. Easy to use and write new plugins. Good documentation and lot of available plugins. Has good admin panel
2. Tigase - Written in java. Very good performances, Mobile optimizations, easy to write plugins.

Both are easy to install and setup. If you have to quick test how it works I suggest you to install openfire and play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly recommend the one given to Openfire (OF) easy configuration via the web. The Openfire has the advantage that is extensible with plugins, making it modular.

As Disadvantaged Openfire consume enough RAM.

Here I leave a link where I explain how to install gnu/linux (not in English, is in Spanish)

http://www.scribd.com/doc/107576024/Instalacion-del-servidor-de-chat-Openfire-v0-1-1